# Mouse Over and Mouse Out Event in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show popup box for user when they hover over a link (mouseover event) and this popup window should disappear when a user leave the link by mouse (mouseout event) ,but the problem is when popup window appear ,user should goes by mouse the popup box ,but in fact the box was disappeared because of the mouseout event for link tab ,so the box is inaccessible (the exact sample is in linkedin.com for showing Account Settings ,Notifications ,Add Connections ,etc in menu bar.
any help ,I would really appreciate.

Comment: Show some code: jsFiddle.net

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a2u/6/)

**CODE :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #navigationbar ul{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
        #navigationbar ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 20px;
            padding:10px;
        }
        #navigationbar ul li a {
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #navigationbar ul span {
            background:red;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var intervals;
    $('.test').mouseover(function(){
        $('.hov').hide();
        var a = $(this).attr('title');
        var b = $(this).parent();
        b.append('<span class="hov" style="top:-5px;">'+a+'</span>');
        intervals= setTimeout( "$('.hov').hide();",2000 );
    });

    console.log('outside'+intervals);
    $('#navigationbar').on('mouseover','.hov',function(){
        clearTimeout(intervals);
    });
    $('#navigationbar').on('mouseout','.hov',function(){
        $('.hov').hide();
    });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="navigationbar">
 <ul>
   <li><a class="test" href="#" title="test" >Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="test" href="#" title="test1">About</a></li >
   <li><a class="test" href="#" title="test2">Contact</a></li>
 <ul> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,this is exactly what I have beem looking for

Comment: check this link . Better than above one .

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7a2u/8/

Answer (score 0):

as frenchie and Patsy Issa told you, you should show some code or that you acutally tried! But to save us all some time, you might also want to have a look at [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) & [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)...